# How will the ratification of HTML5 affect JSF, Struts, ASP.NET etc?

Tags: asp.net, jsf, html, struts

There is a lot of chatter about the improvements HTML5 is about to unleash on the web development world. How will this new standard affect web dev frameworks like Faces, Struts, or even ASP.NET? How long will it take them to 'catch up' in order to emit such code? Will controls get deprecated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There will be little effect for quite some time. There are still so many people using browsers that don't support it.

Having said that, in time this situation will gradually change. I don't think that controls will be deprecated because they don't generally render the tags that have been removed from the HTML 5 specification. It is more likely that the controls will be updated to render differently depending on the version of HTML targeted, and that new controls will be added to various frameworks to take advantage of the new tags available in HTML 5. They will have to degrade nicely though. Not an easy task.

Comment: Thanks! Very insightful. Let's see if anything better comes along.